# Space thousand separator and Dot decimal separator in reactable colFormat

Tags: r, reactable

I am using [{reactable}](https://glin.github.io/reactable/) along with [`colFormat`](https://glin.github.io/reactable/reference/colFormat.html) feature to format a table to my needs.

However, for some columns, I need specifically space as thousand separator and dot as decimal separator.

Both thousand and decimal separators depend on the `locales` parameter defined in colFormat and the possible options for these [locales are listed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oe376/6c085406-a698-4e12-9d4d-c3b0ee3dbc4a). I've tried all of them, and none of them use a space as thousand separator and a dot as decimal separator.

Is there a workaround to achieve the format I want while still using reactable? (and not hard formatting my numeric column in characters)

Answer (score 2):

> I need specifically **space** as thousand separator and **dot** as decimal
> separator.

You may achieve the desired output with [cell rendering](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#cell-rendering).
Let's use one of Glin's [examples](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#currency-formatting) and observe the column `NEW`:

```
data <- data.frame(
  USD = c(12.12, 2141.213, 0.42, 1.55, 34414),
  EUR = c(10.68, 1884.27, 0.37, 1.36, 30284.32),
  INR = c(861.07, 152122.48, 29.84, 110, 2444942.63),
  JPY = c(1280, 226144, 44.36, 164, 3634634.61),
  MAD = c(115.78, 20453.94, 4.01, 15, 328739.73),
  NEW = c(11115.78, 2045320453.94, 4.01, 15, 328739.73)
)

reactable(data, columns = list(
  USD = colDef(
    format = colFormat(currency = "USD", separators = TRUE, locales = "en-US")
  ),
  EUR = colDef(
    format = colFormat(currency = "EUR", separators = TRUE, locales = "de-DE")
  ),
  INR = colDef(
    format = colFormat(currency = "INR", separators = TRUE, locales = "hi-IN")
  ),
  JPY = colDef(
    format = colFormat(currency = "JPY", separators = TRUE, locales = "ja-JP")
  ),
  MAD = colDef(
    format = colFormat(currency = "MAD", separators = TRUE, locales = "ar-MA")
  ),
  NEW = colDef(
    cell = function(value) format(value, nsmall = 2, big.mark = " ")
    # cell = function(values) formatC(x = values, digits = 2, big.mark = " ", format = "f")
  )
))
```

Output:
[image]

Is this what you have in mind?